# Wordpress перевод поста в админке, не на странице

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, google-translate

Есть ли какой-то плагин, который бы переводил пост\страницу на нужный язык? 
На сайте два языка работают. Решили добавить третий, все записи уже созданы, я их продублировал при помощи плагина Duplicate и выбрал язык этой записи, но сам текст остался неизменный. Нужно как-то перевести текст на этих страницах внутри самой темы.

**Не** добавить кнопку выбора языка на сайте и чтобы запрос отправлялся на ресурс переводчика, а потом страница обновлялась - вот так не надо

Comment: "На сайте два языка работают." - и как они работают? Без пояснения вопрос смысла не имеет.

Comment: Не очень вас понял но попробуйте использовать плагины Loco Translate, Translatepress

Comment: @KAGGDesign Вручную писались статьи, язык переключался через плагин Lingotek . А новый язык хотим автоматизировать перевод